# With simple-salesforce how can i trigger case ownership email?

Tags: email, python, simple-salesforce

I am using simple-salesforce to assign a case to an agent from a Queue. If I do this via the application i have the check box that says "send email notification" as pictured below.

[image]

How can i trigger that same option via code using Simple-Salesforce?

Current Case assignment code looks like this and will actually assign the case but does not trigger the email:

```
case = SFType("Case", session_id, instance)
# Get the actual record Id for the case
case_id = sf.query(f"SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber ='{case_id}'").get('records')[0]['Id']
# Set the Owner Id
update_data["OwnerId"] = tsa_id
case.update(case_id, update_data)
```

not sure if i can do something like `case.send_email(ownerId)` but just wondering if that email trigger is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution that works.

The solution was emailSimple invoke option from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_actions_invocable_standard.htm

For the issues on the simple salesforce github page, there was solution at the i used to customize the API to make it easy.

Just add the following method to the simple salesforce api.py file:

```
def invoke_action(self, action, data, method='POST', **kwargs):
    """Makes an HTTP request to an action endpoint."""
    url = "{b}actions/standard/{a}".format(
        b=self.base_url,
        a=action,
    )
    result = self._call_salesforce(
        method,
        url,
        data=json.dumps(data),
        **kwargs
    )

    try:
        response_content = result.json()
    # pylint: disable=broad-except
    except Exception:
        response_content = result.text

    return response_content
```

and to call it use `SF.invoke_action('emailSimple', {'inputs': [{'emailAddresses': 'email1@gmail.com', 'emailBody': 'body 1', 'emailSubject': 'subject 1'}, {'emailAddresses': 'email2@gmail.com', 'emailBody': 'body 2', 'emailSubject': 'subject 2'}]})`.

The discussion about adding this to simple salesforce and dellsystem's solution can be found here: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/163